# java image byte array to grayscale back to image

Tags: arrays, image-processing

I am trying to code image processing, so I have created a method that takes in a `BufferedImage` and make it into a byte array (method name `convertToByteArray(BufferedImage inImg)`).

Then I grab either the ARGB or RGB values from the byte of each pixel (8bit each, using bitwise transformation).  Then append the int value of either ARGB or RGB back into byte array (method name `convertToGrayscale(byte[] inImg)`).

Then feed the byte array to a method to convert back to image (method name `convertToBufferedImage(byte[] inImg)`).

For some reason, when I pass the `BufferedImage` into the method to turn it into a byte array, then with no alteration, pass the byte array into the method to convert back to `BufferedImage` it WORKS.

Here is where I am having problems.  When I pass the `BufferedImage` into method to convert to byte array, then into method to change it into grayscale and within the same method change the grayscale int value into byte array.  HERE is the problem, when I pass the altered byte array into the method to convert back to `BufferedImage`... the result is "**img is null**"  Please help, either my conversion is wrong or i dont know where or what went wrong.

```
public byte[] convertToByteArray(BufferedImage inImg) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    try {
        ImageIO.write(inImg, "jpg", baos);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    outImgByte = baos.toByteArray();

    System.out.println("img to byte array length: " + outImgByte.length);
    System.out.println("convert to byte array complete...");
    return outImgByte;
}

public BufferedImage convertToBufferedImage(byte[] inImg) {
    try {
        outImg = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(inImg));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("convert byte array to image complete...");
    return outImg;
}

public void convertToGrayscale(byte[] inImg) {
    int r, g, b;
    int grayscale;
    // for loop to change each byte value into gray scale
    for(int i = 0; i < inImg.length; i++) {
        // first must get the value of RGB out from byte 
        // array and get the average
        r = (inImg[i] >> 16) & 0xff;
        g = (inImg[i] >> 8) & 0xff;
        b = (inImg[i]) & 0xff;

        grayscale = (r + g + b) / 3;

        outImgByte[i] = (byte) (grayscale << 16 | grayscale << 8 |   grayscale);
    }
    System.out.println("byte to grayscale byte array length: " + outImgByte.length);
    System.out.println("convert to grayscale from byte array complete...");
}
```

Console output:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: image == null!
at javax.imageio.ImageTypeSpecifier.createFromRenderedImage(Unknown Source)
at javax.imageio.ImageIO.getWriter(Unknown Source)
at javax.imageio.ImageIO.write(Unknown Source)
at Main.main(Main.java:50)
```

Comment: That error would occur in `convertToByteArray` not `convertToBufferedImage`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Behind a `BufferedImage`, there is an array, and more than likely a byte array (or sometimes short). So if your `BufferedImage` is of type `TYPE_BYTE_GRAY`, `TYPE_3BYTE_BGR`, or `TYPE_4BYTE_ABGR`, then you can directly access the `DataBuffer` using this: `byte[] databuffer = ((DataBufferByte)image.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData() ;`. It's a direct access to the pixels values. However doing this, you have to manage yourself the image encoding, so this will not work if the `BufferedImage` is of type `TYPE_USHORT_GRAY`.

If you want an easier way (but slower) to access the pixels values, use the Raster:

```
BufferedImage image = ...
for (int y=0 ; y < image.getHeight() ; y++)
    for (int x=0 ; x < image.getWidth() ; x++)
        for (int c=0 ; c < image.getRaster().getNumBands() ; c++)
            final int value = image.getRaster().getSample(x, y, c) ; // Returns the value of the channel C of the pixel (x,y)
```

So using `getSample` and `setSample`, you access and modify the pixels values, without having to manage the image encoding, but it's slower than a direct access to the `DataBuffer`.

Moreover, a `BufferedImage` is almost never encoded using `TYPE_INT_RGB` (or other `INT` encoding), which means that when you access the pixels values using `getRGB`, you ask the image to convert the pixel value into `INT`, and then you have to decompose the value again. So you do the conversion twice. In general, the method `getRGB` has to be banned. It is much slower than using the Raster.

[EDIT]
In your case with an image of type `TYPE_BYTE_GBR`, you can access the pixel values using `byte[] databuffer = ((DataBufferByte)image.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData()`. CAUTION, it's a direct access to the pixels, so if you modify a value into this array, then a pixel will be modified. The encoding is `[b1, g1, r1, b2, g2, r2, ... bN, gN, rN]` for an image with `N` pixels: so (b, g, r) triplets.

Your method `convertToByteArray` becomes:

```
public byte[] copyIntoByteArray(BufferedImage inImg)
    {
    byte[] result = null ;
    switch ( inImg.getType() )
        {
        case BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR:
            byte[] databuffer = ((DataBufferByte) inImg.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData() ;
            result = new byte[databuffer.length] ;
            System.arraycopy(databuffer, result, databuffer.length) ;
            break ;
        // Other encodings
        default: throw new IllegalArgumentException("Not supported.") ;
        }

    System.out.print("img to byte array length: " + databuffer.length) ;
    System.out.println(", convert to byte array complete...") ;
    return result ;
    }
```

[EDIT 2]

```
public BufferedImage ByteArrayToBufferedImage(byte[] src, final int width, final int height)
    {
    // Check first that width*height*3 == src.length
    BufferedImage result = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR) ;
    System.arraycopy(src, ((DataBufferByte)result.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData(), src.length) ;
    return result ;
    }
```

Comment: hi FiReTiTi, thank you very much for your help and information.  I tried using the DataBuffer and .getRaster() to get the byte array from an image.  Now that I used that method, the conversion from byte array to image without altercation doesn't even work (image -> byte array -> image).  before (image -> byte array -> image) works, it was (image -> byte array -> grayscale -> image) doesn't work.  I got a comment above from Chris stating that it seems something went wrong in my grayscale method.  I dont or cant seem to find where or what went wrong.

Comment: What is the type of your image?

Comment: image is "jpg" with no alpha raster, not sure if this what you're asking.

Comment: I was asking the BufferedImage type (TYPE_BYTE_GRAY, TYPE_BYTE_BGR, etc.) that you can get with getType()

Comment: I got a return value of 5 which is equal to TYPE_3BYTE_BGR

Comment: hi FiReTiTi, once again, thank you for your help with this.  I have a question, I don't understand why you are copying databuffer to result, are they not the same thing (byte array)?

Comment: I can return the pointer on the BufferedImage DataBuffer, but then whatever modification you will perform on the byte array will also modify the image.

Comment: so I used the above algorithm to convert the image to byte array and then back to image, I did a check to see if the image is "null" and it is still null

   'code' 
   // base on stackoverflow advice
    byte[] db = ((DataBufferByte) inImg.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();
    byte[] outImgByte = new byte[db.length];
    System.arraycopy(db, 0, outImgByte, 0, db.length);
   '/code'

Comment: Which variable is null? Because I use the code you just wrote everyday and it works fine. And btw, it's the same code I wrote in the method copyIntoByteArray

Comment: so ultimately I need to change convert byte array into double array or int array to modify the RGB, then either change them back to byte array then back to an image or keep them as a int array or double array and then back to image (i am no where near this part yet)  so now I am stuck on image to byte array and then back to image and the error message i get is that the image is a NULL.

Comment: `public BufferedImage convertToBufferedImage(byte[] inImg) {
  try {
   outImg = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(inImg));
  } catch (IOException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
  
  System.out.println("check if IMAGE is NULL: " + outImg);
  System.out.println("convert byte array to image complete...");
  return outImg;
 }`

Comment: I am trying to do this in Java, I was wondering if you can point me in the right direction, as in to what libraries to look at or algorithms.  I've gotten where I converted the byte[] into a double[] I couldn't find anything online to use the double[] to manipulate the image.  Everything I found is using the int[].  For resizing I am looking into bilinear interpolation.

Comment: I've never seen a conversion using ImageIO, so I guess it just does not work. I've edited my code to show you how to do the conversion byte array to image. Look at ImageJ for Java image processing, and there is also Java OpenCV.

Comment: thank you FiReTiTi for all your help and information.  much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

The function `ByteArrayToBufferedImage` is works perfectly.
But, here is what I change the function a little

```
    public BufferedImage ByteArrayToBufferedImage(byte[] src, final int width, final int height) {
        //create empty bufferedImage
        BufferedImage result = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY);
        //remove System.arraycopy (fill empty image with input byte array)
        result.getRaster().setDataElements(0, 0, width, height, src);
        return result;
    }
```

I have no reason for using `result.getRaster().setDataElements` rather than `System.arraycopy` 
If there is anyone who knows any different, please compare these two methods. Thank you